# I cannot use Plugin Finder Service to download my needed plugins, Java and Adobe Flash Player

Tags: plugins

I have tried downloading them, and I am not 100% sure how to use the terminal.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Install an application called `ubuntu restricted extras` from *Ubuntu Software Center*. It will do all this for you - no need to even run it.